# android-streaming mp3 file to other device

Tags: android, audio, stream, media, rtp

First of all, I'm not good at english. sorry.
What I want to make is music broadcasting service.
When I select music from android device, it sended to the server in real time, and server broadcasts it to another.

But I don't know how to send mp3 file to server in real time.

Can I get some ideas or samples?

Please help me....I searching for example codes for a long time but I can get anything....

I have tried AudioStream, but it looks like can send MIC only.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you select a music file, mp3 for instance, there will be no ACTION broadcast. So you can't capture this operation through BoradcastReceiver.
2. You can create an app for user to choose when they select a music file, then you can send the file to server as you like in your app. This can be done by adding intent-filter in your Manifest file.
   Hope this helps you.